# Add active class on Link in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following:

```
class Link extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <li data-id={this.props.el}>{this.props.el}</li>
        );
    }
}

class Nav extends React.Component {
    render () {
        var links = ['name', 'color', 'design', 'share'],
            newLinks = [],
            that = this;
        links.forEach(function(el){
            newLinks.push(<Link activeClass={that.props.active} key={el} el={el} />);
        });
        return (
            <ul>
                {newLinks}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

the value of this.props.active could be " 'name', 'color', 'design', 'share' " same as the array.

Based on that value I would like to assign an active class to the matching li with same data-id={this.props.el} value..

Comment: I don't quite understand your last sentence. So what active class do you want?

Comment: If I get the value back of color from "that.props.active" I want to assign an 'active' class to the li that has the same "data-id" value (data-id={this.props.el}). Unless there is a better way which I would be happy to find out...

Comment: I'm supposing this isn't the router `Links` component. so... there should be an `activeClass` variable no? If not, then why not assign another variable to `that.props.active` e.g. `el2={that.props.active}` and then use `el2` to figure out your logic. (Sorry might still be missing something)

Comment: it's not a router, it's a simple navigation that will keep track of a linear process..

Comment: why not do something (in `class Link`) like `className={ (this.props.activeClass == this.props.el) ? this.props.activeClass : "" }` You are matching the `activeClass` to `el` right?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Link extends React.Component {
    render () {
       var liClass = this.props.isActive ? 'active' : '';
        return (
            <li className={liClass} data-id={this.props.el}>{this.props.el}</li>
        );
    }
}

class Nav extends React.Component {
    render () {
        var links = ['name', 'color', 'design', 'share'],
            newLinks = [],
            that = this;
        links.forEach(function(el){
            newLinks.push(<Link isActive={el === that.props.active} key={el} el={el} />);
        });
        return (
            <ul>
                {newLinks}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: that will assign a class to all of them, I just need an active class based on the vlaue coming from "that.props.active". If the value is color assign a class active to the color Li

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

```
class Link extends React.Component {
   render () {
       return (
          <li className={this.props.activeClass} data-id={this.props.el}>{this.props.el}</li>
       );
   }
}

class Nav extends React.Component {
    render () {
        var links = ['name', 'color', 'design', 'share'],
        newLinks = [],
        that = this;
        links.forEach((el, i)=>{
            newLinks.push(<Link activeClass={that.props.active == el ? 'active': ''} key={i} el={el} />);
        });
        return (
           <ul>
               {newLinks}
           </ul>
       );
    }
}
```